# JSON to HTML: why are values for JSON undefined?

Tags: jquery, json, yql

I'm a JSON noob and trying to fiddle around with the open table of World Cup stats talked about here (http://yhoo.it/ydnworldcup2010).

The below (from a demo I found, just with the YQL call for getJSON and the div's renamed) returns a list of "undefined" 's. How can I get it to return the actual data?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>World Cup JSON attempt</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D%22http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub%3Fkey%3D0AhphLklK1Ve4dEdrWC1YcjVKN0ZRbTlHQUhaWXBKdGc%26single%3Dtrue%26gid%3D1%26x%3D1%26output%3Dcsv%22%20and%20columns%3D%22surname,team,position,time,shots,passes,tackles,saves%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?', function (data) {
        $("#content").html('');
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        $("#content").append('<div class="results"><div class="surname">' + item.surname + '</div><div class="team">' + item.team + '</div><div class="position">' + item.position + '</div><div class="time">' + item.time + '</div><div class="shots">' + item.shots + '</div><div class="passes">' + item.passes + '</div><div class="tackles">' + item.tackles + '</div><div class="saves">' + item.saves + '</div><div class="clear"></div></div>');
});
    });
    $("#content").fadeIn(2000);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
<h4>Results:</h4>
<div id="content"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if it's supposed but the HTTP request you're calling in getJSON returns a piece of JavaScript (a function call), not a piece of JSON. Oh, it's JSONP. Cool, just learned something new.

Comment: @Martinho: That's JSONP.  It's working as intended.

Comment: @SLaks, yeah a quick check in the docs for [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) lead to a quick check at wikipedia for [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
$.each(data.query.results.row, function (i, item) {
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/WWHWw/

The data you're looking for was nested much deeper in the response.

To observe the data returned, you can simply log it to the browser's console, and expand the object to see its properties:

```
console.log( data );
```

Comment: awesome. how can I get the browser to get the data when the page loads, rather than when I run it from the console in Firebug?

Comment: @nathanbweb: I just meant that you can use the console to observe the data. The only change you need to your code is the first line in my answer. Because you're doing it inside `$(document).ready`, it will run when the page loads. So just replace `$.each(data,func...` with `$.each(data.query.results.row, func...`.

Comment: ...the example I posted is just a site called `jsFiddle` that lets you test javascript code. That isn't the console.

Comment: it's weird, my Firefox loads the page and says 'done' without displaying any data. Chrome displays the data on load. I'll keep clearing the cache and see if I can get it to show.. anyway, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is try and understand the layout of the JSON response. The response is a "layered" json reply, meaning you have nested data you're attempting to parse through. I've adjusted your script, and here's a running example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keWVL/).

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D%22http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub%3Fkey%3D0AhphLklK1Ve4dEdrWC1YcjVKN0ZRbTlHQUhaWXBKdGc%26single%3Dtrue%26gid%3D1%26x%3D1%26output%3Dcsv%22%20and%20columns%3D%22surname,team,position,time,shots,passes,tackles,saves%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?', function (data) {

    $("#content").html('');
    $.each(data.query.results.row, function (i, item) {
    $("#content").append('<div class="results"><div class="surname">' + item.surname + '</div><div class="team">' + item.team + '</div><div class="position">' + item.position + '</div><div class="time">' + item.time + '</div><div class="shots">' + item.shots + '</div><div class="passes">' + item.passes + '</div><div class="tackles">' + item.tackles + '</div><div class="saves">' + item.saves + '</div><div class="clear"></div></div>');
        });
    });
    $("#content").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Note: of you use `console.log(data)` inside your getJSON function, you'll be able to see in chrome inspector or firebug what the returned object looks like, then you can properly parse the response.